# How can I set the ng-change attribute on some mark up inside my custom directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a custom directive that contains a `<select>` and an `<input>`.

If I put `<my-custom-directive ng-change="vm.someFunction()">`, how can I add the `ng-change` to the `<select>` inside the markup in the template of the directive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass functions to your directive's scope by using '&'. So when you define your directive, specify the scope the following way:

```
scope: {
'myChangeFunction' : '&'
}
```

In your template you can use it

```
<select ng-change="myChangeFunction()">
```

In your client code you can specify this:

```
<my-custom-directive my-change-function="vm.someFunction()">
```

Answer (score 0):

If I don't misunderstand your question,  you want to add the directive ng-change to a select inside the directive template. Just add the ng-change to the select and handle the event in the directive's controller.

The directive template:

```
<select ng-model="model.id" ng-change="selectChange()">
  <option value="0">Zero</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
 <option value="2">Two</option>
```

The directive:

```
  app.directive("testDirective", function(){
   return{
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'testDirective.html',
    controller: function($scope){
        $scope.selectChange = function(){
          console.log('select change!');
        }
     }
   }
  })
```

Take a look at this plunker.

http://plnkr.co/edit/U184Z8rSjxa6NFEw0n4t?p=preview